# Vuetify display class to hide content based on screen size not working

Tags: css, vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify version 2.3.10. The issue I am facing here is that the I am not able to use the vuetify display css to hide the image based on screen size. Both the images appear on all screen size. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container container--fluid>
      <v-toolbar prominent id="navbar">
        <router-link :to="'/'" title="Main Menu">
          <span class="title hidden-sm-and-up"><img src='../../images/cup.png' id="brand-logo"/></span>
          <span class="title hidden-xs-only"><img src='../../images/logo.png' id="brand-logo"/></span>
        </router-link>
      </v-toolbar>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide an online reproduction in CodePen or otherwise?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. [Demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-galois-9rljd?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)